# Крипто про, ключ в реестре и синий экран

Tags: windows, криптография, реестр, криптопро

Похоже повредилось чтото системное в винде при жестком выключении. Теперь на старте синий экран. На той винде был в реестре ключик криптопро. Как его достать? Реестр это реестр виндовс? В каких ветках он сидит? Может получится с восстановления системы подключить реестр и экспортировать его оттуда. Резервная копия ключа есть, но не помнит никто от неё пароль.

Comment: https://serveradmin.ru/perenos-konteynerov-zakryityih-klyuchey-i-sertifikatov-cryptopro/

Comment: https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&t=3577

Comment: Спасибо, утром попробую